# What governs columns rendered in Azure CLI determined for output table

Tags: azure, azure-cli, jmespath

When I go like this, I get a nice table view, which (awesomely too) pretty much always contains just what I need.

> az ad app list --all
> --output table

Now, as a true developer (read: problem solver), while totally satisfied, I just had to find me a problem solve. So I asked myself: can I [alter the set of columns](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/azure-cli-table-output-columns-jesse-newgard/), ordering, naming etc. Well, I can.

> az ad app list --all
> --output table
> --query "[?contains(displayName,  '-SC')].{Name:displayName, AppId:appId}"

But then, what's the **default** setting and how can I horse around with it? According to [a GH post](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/14197#issuecomment-882885685), it's supposed to be defined in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/format-output-azure-cli#table-output-format) but in the *notes* section, they only mention which fields will be excluded by default.

I wonder where I can find info on:

1. what fields are picked to be included (which isn't all there are),
2. how the order is decided (it can't be random, can it?), and
3. what sets the column names (those aren't verbatim copy of the fields' names).

Answer (score 0):

> 1. how the order is decided (it can't be random, can it?)

No it is not random, order is based on alphabetical order as below:

[image]

> what sets the column names

Column names are set by the Azure Developers at the time of creation of this command and the columns names can be changed if there is an update from developing team(by Microsoft Documents).

> can I alter the set of columns ordering, naming etc:

I agree, by using below command(using -query):

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if we understood each other correctly. By *column names*, I'm referring to names if the columns in table view (as the sample in question shows), while you're showing JSON formatted output. Also: `az account list --output table` doesn't get the columns in the alphabetical order. Not all the fields are picked and those that are, get a bit different names in the table view. I understand that's set by the developers in Azure but I wonder where it's documented what's the **default** subset and naming. By **alter** I meant altering the default, not my particular output.

Comment: Default cannot be altered AFAIK.

Comment: I suspected that. However, that still doesn't address the question of the order of the columns their names and what subset of fields are picked to display. That should be documented somewhere...

Comment: @KonradViltersten, no these things are not documented

Answer (score 0):

Since the Azure client command `az ad` is using Microsoft Graph API, since mid 2022 <sup>[ref](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/12946#issuecomment-1127842145)</sup>, you can dig into Microsoft Graph API documentation to have some of the information you need.

[This page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-get) is, I believe, the corresponding API endpoint used by the Azure client call.

Digging further that route, we can see that there is an chapter named *Applications*, under [*Microsoft Graph REST API v1.0 endpoint reference*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/overview).

And that chapter teach us that there is an [*application resource type*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/application), which is most likely JSON you are getting as a return from your client call.

The same page lists the [properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/application?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties) of that specific resource type.

Here is a reproduction of those properties at the time of writing this answer:

> | Property | Type | Description |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | addIns | addIn collection | Defines custom behavior that a consuming service can use to call an app in specific contexts. For example, applications that can render file streams may set the addIns property for its "FileHandler" functionality. This will let services like Office 365 call the application in the context of a document the user is working on. |
> | api | apiApplication | Specifies settings for an application that implements a web API. |
> | appId | String | The unique identifier for the application that is assigned to an application by Azure AD. Not nullable. Read-only. Supports $filter (eq). |
> | applicationTemplateId | String | Unique identifier of the applicationTemplate. Supports $filter (eq, not, ne). |
> | appRoles | appRole collection | The collection of roles defined for the application. With app role assignments, these roles can be assigned to users, groups, or service principals associated with other applications. Not nullable. |
> | certification | certification | Specifies the certification status of the application. |
> | createdDateTime | DateTimeOffset | The date and time the application was registered. The DateTimeOffset type represents date and time information using ISO 8601 format and is always in UTC time. For example, midnight UTC on Jan 1, 2014 is 2014-01-01T00:00:00Z. Read-only. Supports $filter (eq, ne, not, ge, le, in, and eq on null values) and $orderBy. |
> | deletedDateTime | DateTimeOffset | The date and time the application was deleted. The DateTimeOffset type represents date and time information using ISO 8601 format and is always in UTC time. For example, midnight UTC on Jan 1, 2014 is 2014-01-01T00:00:00Z. Read-only. |
> | description | String | Free text field to provide a description of the application object to end users. The maximum allowed size is 1024 characters. Supports $filter (eq, ne, not, ge, le, startsWith) and $search. |
> | disabledByMicrosoftStatus | String | Specifies whether Microsoft has disabled the registered application. Possible values are: null (default value), NotDisabled, and DisabledDueToViolationOfServicesAgreement (reasons may include suspicious, abusive, or malicious activity, or a violation of the Microsoft Services Agreement). Supports $filter (eq, ne, not). |
> | displayName | String | The display name for the application. Supports $filter (eq, ne, not, ge, le, in, startsWith, and eq on null values), $search, and $orderBy. |
> | groupMembershipClaims | String | Configures the groups claim issued in a user or OAuth 2.0 access token that the application expects. To set this attribute, use one of the following valid string values: None, SecurityGroup (for security groups and Azure AD roles), All (this gets all of the security groups, distribution groups, and Azure AD directory roles that the signed-in user is a member of). |
> | id | String | Unique identifier for the application object. This property is referred to as Object ID in the Azure portal. Inherited from directoryObject. Key. Not nullable. Read-only. Supports $filter (eq, ne, not, in). |
> | identifierUris | String collection | Also known as App ID URI, this value is set when an application is used as a resource app. The identifierUris acts as the prefix for the scopes you'll reference in your API's code, and it must be globally unique. You can use the default value provided, which is in the form api://<application-client-id>, or specify a more readable URI like https://contoso.com/api. For more information on valid identifierUris patterns and best practices, see Azure AD application registration security best practices. Not nullable. Supports $filter (eq, ne, ge, le, startsWith). |
> | info | informationalUrl | Basic profile information of the application such as app's marketing, support, terms of service and privacy statement URLs. The terms of service and privacy statement are surfaced to users through the user consent experience. For more info, see How to: Add Terms of service and privacy statement for registered Azure AD apps. Supports $filter (eq, ne, not, ge, le, and eq on null values). |
> | isDeviceOnlyAuthSupported | Boolean | Specifies whether this application supports device authentication without a user. The default is false. |
> | isFallbackPublicClient | Boolean | Specifies the fallback application type as public client, such as an installed application running on a mobile device. The default value is false which means the fallback application type is confidential client such as a web app. There are certain scenarios where Azure AD cannot determine the client application type. For example, the ROPC flow where it is configured without specifying a redirect URI. In those cases Azure AD interprets the application type based on the value of this property. |
> | keyCredentials | keyCredential collection | The collection of key credentials associated with the application. Not nullable. Supports $filter (eq, not, ge, le). |
> | logo | Stream | The main logo for the application. Not nullable. |
> | notes | String | Notes relevant for the management of the application. |
> | oauth2RequiredPostResponse | Boolean | Specifies whether, as part of OAuth 2.0 token requests, Azure AD allows POST requests, as opposed to GET requests. The default is false, which specifies that only GET requests are allowed. |
> | optionalClaims | optionalClaims | Application developers can configure optional claims in their Azure AD applications to specify the claims that are sent to their application by the Microsoft security token service. For more information, see How to: Provide optional claims to your app. |
> | parentalControlSettings | parentalControlSettings | Specifies parental control settings for an application. |
> | passwordCredentials | passwordCredential collection | The collection of password credentials associated with the application. Not nullable. |
> | publicClient | publicClientApplication | Specifies settings for installed clients such as desktop or mobile devices. |
> | publisherDomain | String | The verified publisher domain for the application. Read-only. For more information, see How to: Configure an application's publisher domain. Supports $filter (eq, ne, ge, le, startsWith). |
> | requestSignatureVerification | requestSignatureVerification | Specifies whether this application requires Azure AD to verify the signed authentication requests. |
> | requiredResourceAccess | requiredResourceAccess collection | Specifies the resources that the application needs to access. This property also specifies the set of delegated permissions and application roles that it needs for each of those resources. This configuration of access to the required resources drives the consent experience. No more than 50 resource services (APIs) can be configured. Beginning mid-October 2021, the total number of required permissions must not exceed 400. For more information, see Limits on requested permissions per app. Not nullable. Supports $filter (eq, not, ge, le). |
> | samlMetadataUrl | String | The URL where the service exposes SAML metadata for federation. This property is valid only for single-tenant applications. Nullable. |
> | serviceManagementReference | String | References application or service contact information from a Service or Asset Management database. Nullable. |
> | signInAudience | String | Specifies the Microsoft accounts that are supported for the current application. The possible values are: AzureADMyOrg, AzureADMultipleOrgs, AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount (default), and PersonalMicrosoftAccount. See more in the table. The value of this object also limits the number of permissions an app can request. For more information, see Limits on requested permissions per app. The value for this property has implications on other app object properties. As a result, if you change this property, you may need to change other properties first. For more information, see Validation differences for signInAudience.Supports $filter (eq, ne, not). |
> | spa | spaApplication | Specifies settings for a single-page application, including sign out URLs and redirect URIs for authorization codes and access tokens. |
> | tags | String collection | Custom strings that can be used to categorize and identify the application. Not nullable. Strings added here will also appear in the tags property of any associated service principals.Supports $filter (eq, not, ge, le, startsWith) and $search. |
> | tokenEncryptionKeyId | String | Specifies the keyId of a public key from the keyCredentials collection. When configured, Azure AD encrypts all the tokens it emits by using the key this property points to. The application code that receives the encrypted token must use the matching private key to decrypt the token before it can be used for the signed-in user. |
> | verifiedPublisher | verifiedPublisher | Specifies the verified publisher of the application. For more information about how publisher verification helps support application security, trustworthiness, and compliance, see Publisher verification. |
> | web | webApplication | Specifies settings for a web application. |

*<sup>Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/application#properties</sup>*

Comment: I don't follow. Where in that table does it say which of those fields that will show as columns in table view and with what header for each column?

Comment: The cli call is just using this API call, so, they will all appear, with the listed column header.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. The table does **not** return the full list of properties in the JSON, it orders them non-alphabetically and it assigns the column names that differ from the fields' names. Please run the sample in the question to see the phenomenon and compare it with the data for the same command but with `--output json` or such.